# Evolution Strategies

Tags: evolutionary-algorithm

What is the basic idea behind self adaptive evolution strategies? What are the strategy parameters and how are they manipulated during the run of the algorithm?

Comment: Apart from the basic idea, this differs per algorithm. The basic idea can be found in any paper or textbook on evolutionary algorithms. Voting to close because the question is too broad for SO.

Answer (score 1):

There's an excellent article on [scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Evolution_Strategies) on the Evolution Strategy. I can also recommend the excellent journal article: Beyer, H.-G. & Schwefel, H.-P. Evolution Strategies - A Comprehensive Introduction. Natural Computing, 2002, 1, 3-52.

In the history of ES there have been several ways of adopting strategy parameters. The target of the adaptation generally is the shape and size of the sampling region around the current solution. The first one was the 1/5th success rule, then came the sigma self-adaptation and finally covariance matrix adaptation (CMA-ES). Why is this important? To put it simple: Adaptation of the mutation strength is necessary to maintain the evolution progress in all stages of the search. The closer you come to the optimum, the less you want to mutate your vector.

The advantage of CMA-ES over sigma self-adaptation is that it also adapts the shape of the region. Sigma self-adaption is restricted to axis-parallel adaptions only.

Answer (score 1):

To get a larger picture, the book [Introduction to Evolutionary Computing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540401849) has a great chapter (#8) on parameter control, which self adaptation is part of.

Here is a quote taken from the introductory section:

> Globally, we distinguish two major forms of setting parameter values:
>   **parameter tuning** and **parameter control**. By parameter tuning we mean
>   the commonly practised approach that amounts to finding good values
>   for the parameters Wont the run of the algorithm and then running the
>   algorithm using these values, which remain fixed during the run. Later
>   on in this section we give arguments that any static set of parameters
>   having the values fixed during an EA run seems to be inappropriate.
>   Parameter control forms an alternative. as it amounts to starting a
>   run with initial parameter values that are changed during the run.
>
> Parameter tuning is a typical approach to algorithm design. Such
>   tuning is done by experimenting with different values and selecting
>   the ones that give the best results on the test problems at. hand.
>   However, the number of possible parameters and their different values
>   means that this is a very time-consuming activity
>
> [Parameter control] is based on the observation that finding good
>   parameter values for an evolutionary algorithm is a poorly structured,
>   ill-defined, complex problem. This is exactly the kind of problem on
>   which EAs are often considered to perform better than other methods.
>   It is thus a natural idea to use an EA for tuning an EA to a
>   particular problem. This could be done using two EAs: one for problem
>   solving and another one - the so-called meta-EA - to tune the first
>   one. It could also be done by using only one EA that
>   tunes itself to a given problem, while solving that problem.
>   **Self-adaptation**, as introduced in evolution strategies for varying the
>   mutation parameters, falls within this category

It is then followed by concrete examples and further details.

Answer (score 0):

well the goal behind self adapting in evolutionary computation in general is that algorithms should be general and require as less problem knowledge in form of input parameters you have to specify as possible.
self adapting makes an algorithm more general without the need of problem knowledge to choose the correct parametrisation.